# Can amazon cloudfront be setup to have multiple domains on cloudfront.net

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm wanting to setup amazon cloudfront, however the assets need to be available on both http & https.

I also want to use multiple cnames. e.g.
xyz0.cloudfront.net
xyz1.cloudfront.net
xyz2.cloudfront.net
xyz3.cloudfront.net

Is this possible at all?

From what I've read the only way this can be done is by using a custom cname (xyz0.example.com) but the problem with this is that it forces me to upload our SSL certificate to Amazon in order to work with https and it costs $600 per month!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9):

You can not only serve different sub-domains, but also serve different root domains from a single CloudFront distribution. The two requirements for that would be:

- An ACM Certificate that has all the domains you need CF to serve
- Add those domains in Alternate Domain Names (CNAMES) section
- Pass the host (Origin) header by whitelisting it in the cache behaviors

For detailed info, have a look at [this video](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/multiple-domains-https-cloudfront/) from AWS Premium Support.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple CNAME (a.bam.com, b.bam.com, c.bam.com) for one Cloudfront distribution.

Though you need to upload a wildcard SSL cert (*.bam.com) to support all those CNAMEs.

You can setup SNI Custom SSL ($0 per month) instead of Dedicated IP Custom SSL ($600 per month). More info visit: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/

Comment: Can I do the same for different domains as `bam.com` and `bom.net` ?

Comment: @Vanicius Santana: here is your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56292691/4061061